# An object is moving along the intersection of the plane $y = 3$ and the surface $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I believe the path would be $z = x^2 + 9$? So in parametric form it would be $r(t) = t^2 + 9$? I need to find the equation of the tangent line to the point $(1, 3, 10)$ on the path in parametric form. I'm not sure show.

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects is moving along the plane, we have $y=3$. Therefore its path can be described by the function

$g(x):=~ f(x,3) =~ x^2+9$

We can parameterize this curve simply by $r(t)=(\,t,3,f\,(t,3)~)$.

The tangent line is then given by $\frac{dr}{dt}(t)~=~ (1,0,g'(t))$ 
For $t=1$ we get $r(t)= (1,3,10)$, therefore we need to calculate  $\frac{dr}{dt}(1)$